# Expected the reducer to be a function - React Native, Redux

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, redux

I learning react native and redux and I'm having a problem in my code that i can't solve. 
when I running my code on iPhone simulator (iOS 10.3) I'm getting the error: "Expected the reducer to be a function".

Here is all of my code (very short, very basic):

src/app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import {Header} from 'native-base';

const App = () => {
  return(
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
      <View>
        <Header />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default App;
```

src/reducers/index.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

export default combineReducers({
    libraries: () => []
});
```

index.ios.js:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src/app';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('project', () =>  App);
```

[the exact error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOwKS.png)

Thank you all, 
   Roei.

Comment: Guess you should export a function instead of the result of a function.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment, but it doesn't working. When i'm doing this I'm getting an another error saying "Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure you pass the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducer.

Comment: Your reducer isn't valid. At least that's what the error is saying.

Comment: Hmm, so `libraries: () => []` is not a valid reducer I guess. Sadly I'm not fluent enough in react to know the correct syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much everybody! it worked, seems like `libraries: () => []`  was actually not valid. Thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 1):

A mistake I did was to use `import { reducers } from '../reducers/myReducer';` instead of `import reducers from '../reducers/myReducer';`, which yielded the same error message.